# Is there a subtraction property in probabilities

Tags: probability

If A and B are two independent events, and P(A-B)=P(B), and P(B)=2/5, what is P(A)?

I'm a little bit confused since I thought that 1-P(B) = P(A-B) but then the numbers don't equate to each other.

Comment: What is the event $A - B$?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, I was assuming that A-B would be P(A) - P(A ∩ B)

Comment: So you mean $A \setminus B$?

Comment: "I was assuming that A-B would be P(A) - P(A ∩ B)" Then what stopped you to solve this? Starting from your interpretation, P(B) = P(A) - P(A ∩ B) = P(A) - P(A)P(B) hence P(A) = P(B)/(1 - P(B)) = (2/5)/(1-2/5)= 2/3.

Answer (score 2):

$A\setminus B$ and $B$ are disjoint events whose union is $A\cup B$, so we have $P(A\cup B)=4/5$. There is a standard formula in probability that tells you that
$$P(A)+P(B)=P(A\cup B)+P(A\cap B)$$
By independence $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$, so we can rewrite it as
$$P(A)+2/5 = P(A)\cdot 2/5 + 4/5$$
which can be solved and gives you
$$P(A)=2/3$$

Comment: Oh, great thanks! I didn't know that A-B denotes set difference. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Oh yes sorry, I didn’t say that explicitly. I think in literature $A \setminus B$ and $A-B$ are both used for set difference.